# Android onRequestPermissionsResult utility of super

Tags: android, android-permissions

When I'm using `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, is it useful to keep the super method?

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

If we look at the super method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();
    int index = (requestCode >> 16) & 0xffff;
    if (index != 0) {
        index--;

        String who = mPendingFragmentActivityResults.get(index);
        mPendingFragmentActivityResults.remove(index);
        if (who == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment.");
            return;
        }
        Fragment frag = mFragments.findFragmentByWho(who);
        if (frag == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity result no fragment exists for who: " + who);
        } else {
            frag.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode & 0xffff, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand the point of the super method, maybe just for the log?

Can I safely delete the super method everywhere?

Comment: That's handing permissions requests done in `Fragment`s. If you are aren't requesting permissions from any `Fragment`s, then you don't really have to call the `super` method in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are dealing with `super` methods, check what it is doing by looking its source code. (Ctrl + Click).

In your case, the method `onRequestPermissionsResult` of the class `FragmentActivity` (parent class of `AppCompatActivity`) has the code to forward the results to its fragments. So if you need the results in fragments, it is necessary, otherwise you can remove the super call. Also if you are directly using `Activity` class for your activity, you can remove it.

In the case of `Fragment` the method `onRequestPermissionsResult` has no body. So you can remove the super call.

Answer (score 2):

Not calling `.super()` is no longer an option.  Don't know what version this changed, but Android Studio now insists on calling `.super()` for any subclass of AppCompatActivity.

Oddly the code still compiles and runs even with this error!  I'm guessing this is to keep from breaking old code.  Look for compiler errors in the near future.

**Lesson**:  call `.super()`.  Looks like google *really* wants you to.